# Regeln für neue Getrenntschreibung

Tags: spelling, reformed-orthography, compound

Bei [heise.de](http://heise.de/-1784221) las ich heute im Newsticker "... war tief greifender als ursprünglich gedacht" und wunderte mich, ob dies nach der neuen Schreibung korrekt ist.

Mit einer kurzen Pause hinter dem "tief" klingt es furchtbar. Gibt es einfache Faustregeln, wann man, gemäß neuer Schreibung, Wörter auseinander schreibt und wann verbunden?

Hier der ganze Satz:

> Der Eingriff des US-Medienkonzerns CBS in die Berichterstattung seines
>   Tochterunternehmens CNet News war tief greifender als bisher bekannt.

Bei dem "war" handelt es sich doch um ein Hilfsverb. Ich müsste, wenn ich mir erlaube das getrennt zu schreiben, doch auch schreiben dürfen:

> Der Eingriff des US-Medienkonzerns CBS in die Berichterstattung seines
>   Tochterunternehmens CNet News griff tiefer als bisher bekannt.

**Update:**
Um mehr als ein mulmiges Gefühl vorzubringen möchte ich argumentieren: Veränderungen greifen normalerweise nicht, auch nicht im metaphorischen Sinne. Niemand würde schreiben "eine flach greifende Veränderung" oder "eine hoch greifende". Lediglich die Kombination "tiefgreifend" ist gängig, und sollte daher zusammengeschrieben werden. Aber das ist die Argumentation eines Laien.

Comment: Müsste man den Ausdruck nicht auch, wenn man ihn getrennt schreibt, als "tiefer greifend" steigern? Oder gilt das auch für zusammengesetzte Kombinationen wie "hochrangig" -- "höherrangig"? Nur ein paar Gedanken zum Thema.

Comment: @Elena: Jetzt, da Du 's sagst! `Tiefer greifend` klingt überhaupt nicht mehr so kriminell.

Comment: Das Präsenspartizip eines einfachen Verbs kann zwar adjektivisch verwendet werden, aber ist idR. nicht komparierbar. Diese Eigenschaft haben nur Partizipien von komplexen Verben (mit Vorsilbe oder mehreren lexikalischen Bestandteilen), wozu auch die Kombination aus Adjektiv (oder Adverb) und Verb gehört (manchmal nur mit Partizip gebräuchlich). Also kann _greifend_ allein stehen, _greifender_ hingegen nicht (zumindest nicht als Komparativ, sondern höchstens als stark dekliniertes maskulines Adjektiv). Ob man das gesamte Adjektiv oder nur das Linkselement _tief_ kommandiert, ist Geschmacksache.

Answer (score 5):

Den aktuellen Rechtschreibregeln zufolge sind beide Varianten erlaubt. Wichtig ist nur, dass man in einem Text einheitlich die eine oder die andere Schreibweise verwendet und nicht wechselt. Alles andere wirkt unsicher. Und der Duden vermittelt mir auch den Eindruck, dass man dort nicht weiß, was nun richtig ist. Vergleicht man *tiefgreifend* mit *weitreichend*, so empfiehlt der Duden einmal die getrennte und dann doch wieder die zusammengeschriebene Variante:

> Von Duden empfohlene Schreibung:
> weitreichend
> Alternative Schreibung:
> weit reichend
>
> Von Duden empfohlene Schreibung:
> tief greifend
> Alternative Schreibung:
> tiefgreifend

Allgemein sind die Empfehlungen des Dudens widersprüchlich. Laut Duden ist ausschließlich *kurzfassen* und *kürzerfassen* korrekt, aber *kurz gefasst* ist gegenüber *kurzgefasst* zu bevorzugen. Unter der Annahme, dass *kurz* hier adverbial verwendet wird, dann wäre die Trennung korrekt.

> Er konnte sich kurz fassen, brach dann aber wieder in sich zusammen.

Als Adjektiv jedoch sollte das Wort meiner Meinung nach aber zusammengeschrieben werden.

> Er sendete uns einen kurzgefassten Lebenslauf.

Denn der Lebenslauf kann nicht *gefasst* sein, und somit kann *kurz* nicht *fassen* genauer beschreiben.

Vergleicht man die Häufigkeit von *tiefgreifend* und *tief greifend*, so ist laut [Wortschatz-Portal der Uni Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/) die zusammengeschriebene Variante etwas gebräuchlicher. Betrachtet man ein Google Ngram wird der Unterschied noch deutlicher. Selbiges gilt für das Wortpaar *weitreichend* und *weit reichend*.

Auch scheinen diejenigen, die uns diese Entscheidung abnehmen sollten, sich nicht einig zu sein. Bis 1996 mussten beide Wörter zusammengeschrieben werden, von dort an bis 2004/2006 getrennt und seit der letzten Rechtschreibreform sind beide Schreibweisen gültig.

Kombiniert aus den beiden vorangehenden Fakten und meiner Gedanken bzgl. adverbialer und attributiver Verwendung, empfehle ich die zusammengeschriebene Variante, es sei denn, es ist die adverbiale Verwendung. [Hier](http://www.lektor.at/beliebte-rechtschreibfehler/t-bis-z/tiefgreifend-oder-tief-greifend/) auch ein Beispiel mit *tief greifend*:

> „Tief greifend“ zog der Bagger eine Ladung Algen vom Grund des Sees.

Anhand dieser Verwendung erkennt man auch, dass *tiefer greifend* durchaus sinnvoll ist. Aber ist es nun *tief greifender* oder *tiefer greifend*?

> Der tiefer greifende Bagger zog eine Ladung Algen vom Grund des Sees.
>
> Der tief greifendere Bagger zog eine Ladung Algen vom Grund des Sees.
>
> Diesmal steht uns eine tiefer greifende Veränderung ins Haus.
>
> Diesmal steht uns eine tiefgreifendere Veränderung ins Haus.

Im Kontext des Baggers gefällt mir *tiefer greifende* besser als *tief greifendere*. Im Falle der Veränderung bin ich mir selbst nicht sicher, aber nach meiner zuvor genannten Schlussfolgerung müsste ich hier mit *tiefgreifendere* gehen und habe tatsächlich auch eine leichte Tendenz dazu.

Ich glaube, wir werden heute noch keine Entscheidung treffen, was wirklich richtig oder falsch ist.
Jeder sollte wohl für sich selbst entscheiden, was er für richtig oder falsch erkennt. Eine Regel, auf die man sich beziehen kann, gibt es nicht. Müsste ich eine Faustregel definieren, laute diese:

> Ist mit *tief greifend* die Reichweite in vertikaler, abwärtsgerichteter Richtung gemeint, so schreibt man *tief greifend* getrennt. Drückt man hingegen aus, dass eine Sache von entscheidender Bedeutung ist, so stehen beide Möglichkeiten offen.

---

Anmerkung:

Die Formulierung *griff tiefer* passt als Vergleich nicht so gut, da hier *greifen* als Verb verwendet wird. *Tiefgreifend*, ob mit oder ohne Leerstelle, ist aber ein Adjektiv. Aus *Das Auto war schnell* machst du ja auch nicht *Das Auto schnellte*.

---

Comment: Nur der Pfeil schnellte vom Bogen. Die Bounty schnellt aber noch nicht so flugs. Vielleicht kommt noch ein Sprachheld mit etwas, das über zeugender ist.

Comment: Na, ein Auto kann schon um die Kurve schnellen ;)

Comment: Vielleicht war es jetzt ungünstig von mir ein Beispiel zu wählen, wo das Verb eine vergleichbare Bedeutung hat, welche man auch tatsächlich sinnvoll anwenden kann. Das Verb *schnellen* hat aber in aller Regel eine leicht differenzierte Aussage, es geht nämlich eher um die ruckartige Beschleunigung. Ich wollte nur ein sinnbildliches und verständliches Beispiel wählen. Hätte ich jetzt "Das Auto war klein" -> "Das Auto verkleinerte sich" oder "Das Auto ist schön" -> "Das Auto schönt" gewählt, wäre die Kritik gewesen, dass das ja auch semantisch gar keinen Sinn mache.